# Непонятный mutable borrow occurs here

Tags: rust

Есть код типа такого (для вопроса сильно урезан):

```
struct WTF<'a> {
    lines: Vec<&'a str>,
    line: &'a str,
    pos: usize,
}


impl<'a> WTF<'a> {
    fn new() -> WTF<'a> {
        WTF {
            lines: vec!["foo", "bar"],
            line: "",
            pos: 0,
        }
    }

    fn read(&mut self) -> &str {
        self.line = self.lines[self.pos];
        self.pos += 1;
        self.line
    }

    fn foo(&mut self) {
        let line = self.read();
        self.read();
        println!("{:?}", line);
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut wtf = WTF::new();
    wtf.foo();
}
```

Обратите внимание на `fn foo`. Из-за неё Rust мне пишет вот такую ошибку:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
24 |         let line = self.read();
   |                    ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
25 |         self.read();
   |         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
26 |         println!("{:?}", line);
27 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

Однако можно переписать эту функцию по-другому:

```
fn foo(&mut self) {
    self.read();
    let line = self.line;
    self.read();
    println!("{:?}", line);
}
```

Второй вариант (вроде бы) полностью эквивалентен первому. Но компилируется и работает как надо!

Я не понимаю, что компилятору не понравилось в первом варианте? Почему он считает, что там есть mutable borrow до самого конца функции? И почему тогда во втором варианте он так не считает?

Если я поменяю `let line` на `let mut line`, ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если расписать времена жизни, которые Rust проставляет по-умоланию в функции `read()` получим:

```
fn read<'x>(&'x mut self) -> &'x str
```

У параметра `self` и возвращаемого значения одно время жизни. Это приводит к тому, что Rust считает, что происходит заимствование `self` на время пока результат функции не выйдет из области видимости.

Похожий случай описан в [Растономиконе](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html) ([перевод](https://github.com/ruRust/rustonomicon/blob/master/src/lifetime-mismatch.md)) для иллюстрации того, как система проверки заимствований может "промахиваться".

В вашем примере можно избежать заимствования, если явно указать, что время жизни возвращаемого значения функции `read()` должно быть равно времени жизни ссылки, хранящейся в структуре `WTF<'a>`:

```
fn read(&mut self) -> &'a str
```

или без сокращений:

```
fn read<'x>(&'x mut self) -> &'a str
```

Несмотря на то, что *borrow checker* временами слишком строг и с ним сложно "договориться", он во многих случаях спасает от "выстрела в ногу".
Разработчики Rust планируют улучшить его работу, но существенных изменений в ближайшее время ждать не стоит. Если интересно можете почитать серию статей Нико Матсакиса о [нелексических временах жизни](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/04/27/non-lexical-lifetimes-introduction/).